# How to disable Intellij documentation popup?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a mac pro for work and use vim bindings in Intellij so I reach for esc quite a bit. The touch bar is really sensitive so I end up hitting F1 quite a bit. Normally its benign but the last 2 days the documentation pane is popping up and I have to jump to the track pad to close it. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At **IntelliJ IDEA | Settings | Keymap** you can search for "*Quick Documentation*" and right-click on top of it to "Remove F1" or switch to a different shortcut.

Additionally, you can make sure by disabling "*Show quick documentation on hover*" under **Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Editing**